# Common js default export doesn't work when transpiling with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, commonjs

Am using a webpack basic configuration and when i use the basic export from common js it doesn't works.

webpack.config.js

```
var commonJsConfig = {
  target: "node",
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "hello.node.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs",
  },
};

module.exports = commonJsConfig;
```

When i do this:

src/index.js file

```
function hello() {
  console.log("hello");
}

module.exports = hello;
```

test.js

```
const hello = require("./dist/hello.node");
console.log(hello);
hello();
```

the function hello is printed like an empty object however if i do this:

src/index.js file

```
function hello() {
  console.log("hello");
}

module.exports = { hello };
```

test.js

```
const hello = require("./dist/hello.node").hello;
console.log(hello);
hello();
```

It works just fine

I am wondering why is that, i don't get why module.exports = hello doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed it for me was just changing the library target to `commonjs-module` like so:

```js
var commonJsConfig = {
  target: "node",
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "basic-indexer.node.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs-module",
  },
};

module.exports = commonJsConfig;
```